# how to Add zero on the left of decimal number?

Tags: vb.net, string, character, decimal, ascii

This code for convert from Ascii to decimal, but i couldn't add zero on left of (2 digit)

```
Dim sText As String 
Dim i As Integer 
Dim lenText As Integer 
sText = TextBox6.Text 
lenText = Len(sText) 
For i = 1 To lenText 
    sASC = sASC & CStr(Asc(Mid$(sText, i, 1))) 
Next i 
m = sASC `
```

Comment: This code will take a string, and concatenate the ascii of each character in the string. So "ABC123" >> 656667495051. Please clarify what your question "how to Add zero on the left of decimal number?" relates to your code or vice-versa.

Comment: Ex:
I input my name in textbox.text
(qussai) in Decimal = 11311711511597105
but i want the result like this:
0113,0117,0115,0115,0097,0105
and i want to make operation to each 4 digit.
Ex:
0113^5=18424351793
0117^5=21924480357
.
.
.
.
the output will be like this:
1842435179321924480357.
do you got it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the commented code with some linq

```
'For i = 1 To lenText
'    sASC = sASC & CStr(Asc(Mid$(sText, i, 1)))
'Next i

sASC = sText.
    Select(Function(t) String.Format("{0:0000}", Asc(t))).
    Aggregate(Function(t1, t2) t1 & "," & t2)
```

It will re-select your numbers, formatted to always have [at least] 4 characters, with any leading extra spaces being 0. Then it will put the results together (aggregate), joined by a ",".

> input: qussai
>
> output: 0113,0117,0115,0115,0097,0105

Judging by additional information in your comment, a string is not the best vehicle at that point in your code. You have numeric values from `Asc()`, then you will do numeric operations in raising to 5th power. It would be best to use the Asc values to do your math, then make a string. Do this for the desired result:

```
sASC = sText.
    Select(Function(t) Math.Pow(Asc(t), 5).ToString()).
    Aggregate(Function(t1, t2) t1 & t2)
```

> input: qussai
>
> output: 18424351793219244803572011357187520113571875858734025712762815625

Comment: Thanks very much, Its work,
but could you put this

c = BigInteger.Pow(t, 47) Mod 1073

in same code!

Comment: this is in Decimal and i want ot input it:
"912,697,583,1065,261"
and i want to do operation to each group of numbers between comma and then convert it to Ascii???

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, you want to pad with a single zero each decimal value of two digits of the resulting string, then you can do it in this way:

```
<HideModuleName>
Public Module StringExtensions

    <Extension>
    Public Function ToDecimals(ByVal sender As String) As String

        Dim sb As New StringBuilder(capacity:=(sender.Length * 3))
        For Each c As Char In sender
            sb.AppendFormat("{0:000}", Convert.ToInt32(c))
        Next c
        Return sb.ToString

    End Function

End Module
```

Usage:

```
Dim dec As String = "ABC".ToDecimals()
Console.WriteLine(dec)
```

That will produce:

> 065066067

---

### UPDATE

```
Private Sub ButtonCalc_Click() Handles ButtonCalc.Click

    Dim input As String = Me.TextBox1.Text
    Me.TextBox2.Text = StringToDecimals(input)

End sub

' Rehusable function.
Public Shared Function StringToDecimals(ByVal str As String) As String

    Dim sb As New StringBuilder(capacity:=(str.Length * 3))
    For Each c As Char In str
        sb.AppendFormat("{0:000}", Convert.ToInt32(c))
    Next c
    Return sb.ToString

End Function
```

Comment: could you rewrite your code, 
use textbox1.text to input and textbox2.text to output and Button calc.

because  i am beginner and i didn't use (Module) as you wrote.
thanks.

Comment: @qussai See the update please. Welcome to StackOverflow, remember to mark the answer as accepted if I solved your doubt!.